# JavaFx and ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javafx-8

I'm developing a mediaplayer in JavaFX-8, after some research I found ffmpeg, but all the Java wrapper projects for ffmpeg seems to be discontinued.
I'm able to launch the video playback with ffplay

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("F:/ffmpeg/bin/ffplay " + videoLink );
```

but I would like to be able to render the video in a JavaFx Pane instead of an external window.
I should use a wrapper (even if discontinued) or there is a way to get ffplay output in a Pane?

Comment: Instead of reinventing another media player, why not learn C and contribute to VLC, for example?

Comment: Because the mediaplayer is just a part of my application

Comment: JavaFX has a [built-in MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm), perhaps you might wish to use that.

Comment: I looked at it a while ago and it supported only few codecs

Answer (score 0):

I will edit my answer later but I have found this a day
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712

Read the entire post but You can do your media player by integrating vlc directly

Comment: Vlc integration could be a solution, but from what I've understood, vlc has a problem timeshifting http streams that cause this bug [link](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/5093#)